# What is the name of this balloon-like UI component? (Android/Linux)

Tags: android, linux, user-interface, dialog

This is neither a code-question nor technical issue, so I admit that it can be somewhat off-topic with StackOverflow, but I'm in really need of help because I already took lots of time.

I'm working with a help window implementation and I'd like to do this with a type of view that I've seen in some of Android button options. In some versions of Ubuntu, the view can also be seen when you point your mouse arrow within an application shortcut in the main taskbar. It looks like a balloon-type dialog box. Bellow is a screenshoot of the view:

[image]

My issue is a somewhat softheaded one: **I don't know the technical name of this UI component, and so I can't search for documentations and examples.**

I've already searched for several combinations of terms such as **dialog-box, menu, balloon, popup-menu** and so on, without success. Can someone tell me the name of this UI and, if possible, post a simple example of usage in Android/Java?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no native UI with that approach but, you can use any viewgroup you prefer (depending on the content of it) and set the background of this viewgroup to be a 9 patch drawable.

Comment: Hi Budius, thanks for the reply. Yeah, it sounds to be a valid solution, but I'm looking for native component (if it exists). I can implement this in the way that you have told, but it will grab some extra time from me as the help-box will handle other views and I will be in need to check the position based on his parent position every time I show it.

Comment: as mentioned by @PeterSlesarew, there are some free/open source libraries to achieve that. I remember there's something called ActionProvider, I've never used so I can't guarantee it will be the answer you want, but you can check it out here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider and here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionProvider.html

Comment: Hi again Budius. Really nice solution. Although ActionProvider isn't the exact thing I'm looking for, it can fit very well on my purposes. I'm accepting this answer as it have, in the moment, the closest docummentation I'm looking for. Thanks so much you, PeterSlesarew and Andy for the helpfull answers.

Answer (score 3):

That looks like a popup.  It's not a standard component, but you can create one like that with [PopupWindow.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

See [how to create popups in Android](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/) for details implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no UI View for that: check http://greendroid.cyrilmottier.com/ There is something like QuickAction. Simple to use and free ;)

[image]